# How to Change Button Border on Click with Multiple Button Sets so only one set is affected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple sets of buttons. Each set has 2 buttons - One is active (with border), Other is inactive (without border). My current solution tuns off all active buttons in all sets, while it should only affect the one in its set. Any idea how to solve this?

```js
$(".MobileSwitcherButton").click(function() {
   $(".MobileSwitcherButton").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.MobileSwitcherButton {border: none;}

.MobileSwitcherButton.active {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="set1">
<img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active" 
id="MobileSwitcherButton1"/>
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" 
alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton"  id="MobileSwitcherButton2"/>
</div>

<div id="set2">
<img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active" 
id="MobileSwitcherButton1"/>
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" 
alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton"  id="MobileSwitcherButton2"/>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to the parent first and remove the class for its children.

```js
$(".MobileSwitcherButton").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".MobileSwitcherButton").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.MobileSwitcherButton {
  border: none;
}

.MobileSwitcherButton.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="set1">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active" id="MobileSwitcherButton1" />
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton" id="MobileSwitcherButton2" />
</div>

<div id="set2">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active" id="MobileSwitcherButton1" />
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton" id="MobileSwitcherButton2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly as it only affects the button inside one set and is really well scalable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up the event handler on the images, set it up on the `div` parent elements. This will allow you to work with individual sets rather than all the sets at once.

Then, in that handler, look for the images (within the `div` that the event was handled on) and remove all `.active` classes from those.

Finally, add back the `.active` class to the element that originated the event.

```js
// Set up the handler on the various image set containers
$("div[id^='set']").click(function(event) {
   // Find all the images within the container that handled the click
   $(".MobileSwitcherButton", this.closest("div")).removeClass("active");
   $(event.target).addClass("active"); // Add the class to the event originator
});
```

```css
.MobileSwitcherButton {border: none;}

.MobileSwitcherButton.active {border: 1px solid black;}

/* Only added to show more sets on one screen for demo: */
img { width:40px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="set1">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton">
</div>

<div id="set2">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton">
</div>

<div id="set3">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton">
</div>

<div id="set4">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton active">
  <img src="https://www.pracovnivozidla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Delivery-Icon.png" alt="" class="MobileSwitcherButton">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. Let's say I will have 20+ sets. Then I don't want to make a new function for each set. Is there a more scalable solution that would work for all sets at once?

Comment: @Krystof My answer needs no adjustments no matter how many sets you have. Do you see that there is only one function for two sets in my answer? Just add or remove sets in the same HTML pattern as the original one and it will work. This is better than setting up event handlers on the images themselves as less handlers are created and therefore less memory is consumed by the DOM objects.

Comment: @Krystof I've added two more sets to show what I mean. Still only one function to handle them all.